# Getting trouble with publishing in HTML5 through Flash & actionsript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Hi there...

```
     I am having a query about how to publish in HTML5 format through flash.
```

I have a .fla file containg animation and Actionscript 3.0, when i publish it to HTML, it ask to download flash player in browser. But it is not necessary to have flash player in the browser while loading the .html file. So plaease guide me for the issue.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what the menu means by publish to HTML. This is simply publishing a SWF file and a corresponding HTML file that has HTML code to embed the SWF. This is not a cross compilation option. Those exist but that's not what you get in Flash CS5 by default.

If you're interested in Cross Compilation from AS3 to HTML/JS you can check out [Randori](http://randoriframework.com/what_is_randori/) and also projects like [FalconJS](https://cwiki.apache.org/FLEX/falcon-overview.html):
http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2011/11/19/what-is-falconjs/

I saw a talk about both of these recently in Chicago by some of the developers.  They both seem like promising concepts (basically dodging the flash player).

The other option if you're trying to develop for mobile deployment is to package your code as an air installer.  This will run your code on top of the AIR runtime (which has support on tons of devices, iOS, Android, Blackberry etc.), but this is not an in the browser experience, but rather a download the app type deal.

From what I got from the two developers (one from Apache Flex, one the creator of Randori) neither wanted to put too much trust into Adobe's platform given it's no longer supported on most mobile devices.

As an aside Adobe also has a product called Edge that allows you to do animation with a similar tool-set to what you get in Flash and exports HTML/JS/CSS.  If you're not interested in AS3 or object oriented programming or type-safe languages cross compiling might not be the best option.  I've personally been playing with AngularJS lately and been liking it due to the parallels with Flex, but there's a lot of great scripts/libraries/frameworks out there, if you explain a bit more of what you're trying to accomplish I can give more directed guidance.